# How can I check if local val is initialized?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've got the following Unit function:

```
private fun loadFilterArea() {
    val query = ALIAS.AREA
    val type = preferences.getInt(query, TYPEVALUES.MY_LOCATION)

    val longitude: Double
    val latitude: Double

    when (type) {
        TYPEVALUES.MY_LOCATION -> {
            ...
            longitude = point.longitude
            latitude = point.latitude
            ...
        }
        TYPEVALUES.CUSTOM_RADIUS -> {
            ...
            longitude = point.longitude
            latitude = point.latitude
            ...
        }
        TYPEVALUES.INPUT -> {
            ...
            longitude = preferences.getFloat(ALIAS.AREA_LONGITUDE, 0f).toDouble()
            latitude =  preferences.getFloat(ALIAS.AREA_LATITUDE, 0f) .toDouble()
            ...
        } else -> {
            ...
        }
    }

    //... the question is here ...
    //... can't be compiled cause val's are not initialized
    if (longitude != null && latitude != null) {
        storeKey(ALIAS.AREA_LONGITUDE, longitude)
        storeKey(ALIAS.AREA_LATITUDE, latitude)
    } 
  }
```

So, how can check if values longitude and latitude are initialized ?

I don't want to move them from function to global scope and use them as lateinit with further ::latitude.isInitialized, and it seems like my version of Kotlin doesn't support local lateinit variables

Comment: if val not initialized it won't compile. So you need to make a decision: early exit (return), default values or throw exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it makes sense to have `null` values for latitude and longitude for your use case, then you can define those variables as nullable `Double`, e.g., `var latitude: Double? = null` (the same for `longitude`). After that, it makes sense to check if they're not `null`, but the variable becomes no more immutable.
In order to keep immutability, you can do something like that:

```
val longitude: Double?
val latitude: Double?

when (type) {
    TYPEVALUES.MY_LOCATION -> {
        longitude = ...
        latitude = ...
        ...
    }

    TYPEVALUES.CUSTOM_RADIUS -> {
        longitude = ...
        latitude = ...
        ...
    }

    TYPEVALUES.INPUT -> {
        ...
    } else -> {
        latitude = null
        longitude = null
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want them to be non-nullable, then you need to provide a meaningful, non-`null` value in all branches of the `when` statement.

Comment: val latitude: Double? = null can't be compiled too, cause of 'val', it will only work with 'var' which i use now, but i want them to be immutable after assigment. Is there any way of doing this with 'val' ?

Comment: right now i'm using custom implementation of NSimon solution, but both of solutions (his and yours one), I think, has no direct answer of my question. I just want to know if it is possible to check if local val is initialized, and if yes - how. Not how to rewrite my code using var or destructing declaration, cause both of that cases means firstly you assign value, then you check that value.

Comment: @NikitaYankov The issue is that if there's any path where that variable is not assigned, your code won't even compile, provided that the variable is used anywhere (e.g., in a `return` statement, in a `println`, etc.), so there's no need to check if the variable is initialized or not, because that's a runtime check, not a compile time check

Comment: yeah, looks like I just missed some things a little, it's kindly hard to move from Java to Kotlin without that paranoic null-safety checks. Thanks for staying tune, I'll mark your question as a correct one.

Comment: Thanks! However, note that the very same compilation issue happens also in plain Java: if you declare a variable without initializing it, and there's at least 1 execution path using that variable without having initialized it before, you'll get a compilation error like `Variable 'xxx' might not have been initialized`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the power of when to store the value directly, so that declaration and assignments are done at the same time:

```
val (latitude, longitude) = when (type) {
  TYPEVALUES.MY_LOCATION -> Pair(0.0, 0.0)
  TYPEVALUES.CUSTOM_RADIUS -> Pair(1.0, 1.0)
  else -> Pair(2d, 2d)
}
//Your latitude is a double
//Your longitude is a double
```

Comment: you can also take advantage of [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations) to have `latitude` and `longitude` variables: `val (latitude, longitude) = when (...) `